# How to know if a Careers 2.0 profile request has been accepted (or not)?

Tags: support, jobs, profile-page

I submitted a request for a Careers 2.0 profile three days ago but didn't get any feedback. When I go to My Profile page, I still see the same form where I can request a profile. So is there any way to know the status of a profile request (whether accepted or rejected)? In general, do we get some feedback on that after someone has reviewed the request?

Comment: in your specific case, I believe we have since got to you and you should have received an invite. Send us an email if you didn't and THANKS for waiting!!

Comment: Yes, the profile has now been accepted, and I got an email for it. Thanks a lot for the reply, it should be useful to others too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is *no* and the wait time may vary quite a bit from the same day if you are lucky on timing to perhaps a few weeks if we are all really busy and less (or none) of us get to looking through the submissions as regularly as we'd like to. Generally speaking, if it's been more than 2 weeks, then for some reason the request is not getting a lot of attention and one should probably try and locate somebody that has invites and wants to invite them in (colleagues or tweet about it maybe) or perhaps just submit something again that is easier or clearer to evaluate.

**Background**: All submitted requests go into a queue and are manually reviewed by our developers or people with a technical background on the Careers team. Lots of these submissions come in and the quality of the submissions varies widely, not to mention spam and bot type requests, invalid email addresses, etc. When going through the submissions, we tend to poke around and first cherry pick the ones that are easiest to process and appear to be "low risk" relative to the decision that the requester should be invited in to create a profile. If it's not clear what has been submitted or why, the requests tend to get thrown back into the queue. This doesn't mean somebody won't get to it later and spend more time on it, but it definitely means that it's going to take longer and it could be that nobody is ever going to bother going through it and may eventually get lost down in the pile with many others like it.

**Tips:** After inviting in nearly 2,000 people myself in the last 6 months, here are a few tips for helpful things to increase the speed or likelihood that you'll be invited by one of us here:

- Full name in real life. (I rarely invite people that I can't easily discover their full name)
- URL to your Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or other Stack Exchange site user profile that has some relevant content.
- URL to an existing CV or completed profile on LinkedIn, etc.
- URL to something technical you wrote or your blog, etc.
- URL to open source projects that you are clearly a contributor to (GitHub, etc.)
- If you give a URL for something and it's not a profile or blog, explain why you are providing that as a reference so we know what we are looking for.
- Whatever you write in the request make it clear and complete. Quality counts.

To be clear, we're not looking for all of the above, we are just looking to be reasonably convinced that you are developer, system admin, or at least have a technical background appropriate for Stack Overflow Careers and that the requester is likely to create a decent quality profile in the system.