# How can I register on Careers?

Tags: support, jobs

How can I register on [careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: For what sort of questions you can ask, check the [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq). Register on Careers by going to Careers and clicking "log in" at the top.

Comment: You'd need an invitation from an existing user or someone on the team.  You can request from the team to get invited, though you'll probably need a decent reputation on Stack Overflow to hope to be accepted.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: how much reputation required?

Comment: The actual amount of rep needed (and other criteria) to trigger the Careers invitation is a tightly-held secret around here.

Comment: Well, to give some sort of ballpark figure, I'm on Careers and my SO rep was probably under 4k when I got the invite.

Comment: Being in the top 20% of a tag (presuambly not all tags) was how I received an invite- would have had around 2.5k rep then...

Comment: Same for me...IIRC, I got the e-mail invitation soon after gettin a silver badge (100 upvotes) for a tag, but that might just be a coincidence; I too think I was little around 3K rep

Comment: @JeffMercado _you'll probably need a decent reputation_  - that's not mandatory - or at least wasn't mandatory this summer when I got Careers profile having rep about zero. Back then, their materials were giving quite a lot of hints how to make a convincing "cover letter" without SO rep

Comment: FWIW I got my invitation saying "We’re impressed by your “java” tag answers on Stack Overflow.". I didn't even have my bronze tag badge at the time! So I guess having answers with upvotes and accepts in a specific tag counts for a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Stack Overflow profiles are **invitation-only**, either by us or by your
>   peers. If you haven’t been invited, ask among your friends and
>   colleagues.
>
> Stack Overflow grants new invites to users fitting certain criteria of
>   **activity on Stack Exchange sites**, including reputation. Participate
>   more, ask good questions, and give good answers. You never know what
>   might appear in your inbox.

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one

Comment: Additional information about submitting requests is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112423/1553)